# How to override toMap method from extends class

Tags: dart

I have a class B extends class A, and it have the toJson method override the class A's toJson method. But when i force class B to class A, the toJson method not be changed from class B to class A.

```
class A {
  String str1;

  A(this.str1);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    'str1': str1,
  }
}

class B extends A {
  String str2;

  B(this.str2, str1) : super(str1);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'str2': str2,
        'str1': str1,
  }
}


void test(A a) {
  print(a.toMap());
}

// When I pass class B in class A parameter, it still use the class B.toMap method.
B b = B('str2', 'str1');
test(b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Dart instance methods are *virtual*, also known has having *dynamic dispatch*. That means that when you call `a.toMap()`, which `toMap` implementation gets called depends on the *runtime type* of the object `a`, not the *static type* of the expression `a`.

So, in this case, you are calling `toMap` on an instance of `B`, so you use `B`'s `toMap`.

This is a fairly common behavior in object oriented languages (dynamic dispatch is one of the hallmark features of object orientation: The object determines how to respond to the message you send it, here the request to do a "toMap" operation.)

Some object oriented languages also have non-virtual methods. Dart does not.
You can either define a static method:

```dart
class A {
  static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(A value) => ...;
}
class B {
  static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(B value) => ...;
}
```

and then choose which one to call:

```dart
  print(A.toMap(a));
```

or you can use extension methods (which are really just static methods with a nicer call syntax) because they dispatch based on the *static type* of the receiver:

```dart
extension AToMap on A {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => ...;
}
extension BToMap on B {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => ...;
}
```

and call it normally:

```dart
  print(a.toMap()); // Chooses AToMap.toMap based on static type of `a`.
```

In most situations, if you really want to access both `A.toMap` and `B.toMap` on an instance of `B`, you're better of renaming one of the methods to avoid the naming conflict.